# Connect an desktop application to my SQL Server using internet

Tags: sql-server, remote, connections

I want to connect a desktop app to a SQL Server using internet, not local. The app will run on every network in the world with internet and the data will retrieve and send from my PC using SQL Server... Do you know how I do that?

I have forwarded the TCP 1433 ports in my DLINK router, and allow in the Windows Firewall, I have tried connect with my public IP into the SSMS but the server does not found. Only using my private IP given by my router 192.168.0.XXX.

Comment: I'm guessing that your ISP perhaps doesn't allow inbound connections. Can you telnet to port 1433? Also, have you allowed remote connections in SQL Server?

Comment: @DanielHutmacher The server allows remote connections, I have telnet my own public IP address using in CMD  "telnet 191.103.12.XXX 1433" but send a message saying "Could not open connectionto the host , on port 1433 " even I have tried with 8080 ports and the same message shows. Also I have tried telnet my private IP with 1433 ports and the connection was stabilished.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you are trying to connect to the external ip address where you on a computer outside of your network. Many routers do not allow you to connect to their external address when you are on the inside of the network. Try this: https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap

Answer (score -1):

The External IP that your router have is probably Dynamic, you have to use a service like "noip"(goggle it) to map into your router IP . The connected string must be noIP.server